# How to hide ModalBottomSheetLayout on Back Press / Back Gesture

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

Im using Compose via ComposeView in a Fragment backed by Graph Navigation.

Im using ModalBottomSheetLayout and need to hide it on back Press.

I have tried using BackHandler, but it is not working.

```
class fragment : Fragment() {
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        return ComposeView(requireContext()).apply {
            setViewCompositionStrategy(ViewCompositionStrategy.DisposeOnViewTreeLifecycleDestroyed)
            setContent {
                BackHandler(true) {
                    Log.i("compose_check","back Pressed") // not getting triggered
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have Overrided `onBackPressed()` in the `Activity`. After removing that, it worked fine.